# Azure Cost Calculator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an existing website and I have been asked to calculate how much it would cost to move this site to azure.

We know azure is the right platform because we need a solution that can scale and shrink according to demand whilst maintaining a high availability.

The site is a ASP.Net MVC running across a three server environment (IIS7) - and SQL Server.

Are there any tools available that I could run alongside the website that would tell me how much the site would cost on azure? If not, what statistics would I need to be able to calculate this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking for us to provide / search for a tool / library are off topic on here. Also this question is too broad and is primarily opinion based.

Comment: I think I'll disagree with @deathismyfriend on this one.  Knowing how much your code is going to cost is very important.  While perhaps not strictly on topic at this moment in time - I would argue that it should be.  This kind of information is important these days.

Comment: @SamAxe - it's still a request for an off-site tool.

Comment: It is important that an ambulance is on time, but we don't ask questions about it here @SamAxe

Comment: Wow, you two totally missed the point.

Comment: @user1474992 - Azure offers a calculator, and for the rest you'll have to do your own estimates and instrumentation. It is easy to monitor.

Comment: @SamAxe just because information is useful, does not mean it is on-topic. If it is off-topic then it is off-topic, no matter how useful it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download the [Azure Cost Estimator Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43376) and you can also use the [Azure App Service Migration Assistant](https://www.movemetothecloud.net/) to do an assessment and migration of your web app

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I was after!